# Convert variable into array

Tags: perl

I have a requirement to send my variable to array. I have something like this:

```
var = "abc|xyz|123";
```

I want to have the above values in an array.

```
$arr[0]="abc";
$arr[1]="xyz";
$arr[2]="123";
```

I used the following way, but I am not getting the array size while using this way:

```
$var = "abc|xyz|123";
$var =~ tr/|/\n/; # transforming "|" to new line "\n"
@a = $var;
print $a[0];
```

The complete transformed output is sent to only variable instead of individual variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
@a = split(/\|/, $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not quite sure what you intend to do, but it seems to me like you're trying to solve a problem on your own which has already a solution?!

This should do the trick: [Using the Perl split() function](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html)?

```
 my $data = 'Becky Alcorn,25,female,Melbourne';
 my @values = split(',', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use split

```
$var = 'abc|xyz|123';
@a = split '|', $var;
print $a[0];
```

Comment: Alas, this will print `a`, because `split` treats the pattern as a regexp and `|` is a regexp metacharacter. (The regexp `|` matches either the empty string or the empty string, which is kind of silly but technically a valid regexp.) To fix it, you should quote the `|` like [Mat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10165204) shows. Also, please test your code before posting it.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the regex
like this

```
$var=~s/(\w+|\d+)/$data[$gg++]=$1;''/eg;
```

now the array @data holds the scalar data in $var...